# How git push for existing folders?

Tags: git, github

I've one feature branch named as `someone.branch`, which is having some new folder structures added with new files.

There is one master branch, `master.branch`, as of now not having newly created folder structures added with new files from `someone.branch`

Now I created a new branch named as `my.branch` from `master.branch`, which is also not having newly created folder structures added with new files from `someone.branch`

So now I created same folder structures in `my.branch` which `someone.branch` is also having but with different files for different purpose.

What would happen, if `someone.branch` merge to `master.branch` first and then `my.branch` to `master.branch` ?

Will it overwrite the files with folders in `master.branch` because when I pushed my code from `local` to `my.branch`, it was showing create mode for all folders and files while pushing into `my.branch` ?

Comment: Git doesn't track directories, only files. Can you update your question with the paste of "create mode for all folders"?

Comment: @choroba you are correct, just checked that..it showed <<create mode>> only for files with complete path with folder structure. So that means, <<my.branch>> will not overwrite the files with new folder structure pushed from <<someone.branch>> to <<master.branch>>...correct ?

Comment: Just try it and you will see, nothing will be lost.